# Small browser frame with no decorations

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to figure out how to create a small browser window with no decorations.  That is no address bar, no tabs, no bookmarks bar, no minimize/maximize/restore buttons.  The only button it has is a small close button.  I am trying to create a window that looks like this: dropbox.com/s/xed7p94s1kpnwrg/Smallwindow.png?dl=0

I tried this Javascript, and it is close, but it still leaves the address bar.  If I could just get rid of that, it would be great.

```
<head>
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    var features =  ""  
                    + "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,personalbar=no"
                    + ",status=no,chrome=yes,resizable,centerscreen"
                    //+ ",width=400"        //Width of content window
                    //+ ",height=200"       //Height of content window
                    + ",outerWidth=400"   //Width of window
                    + ",outerHeight=200"  //Height of window
                    + ",top=500"
                    + ",left=600"
                    ;
    window.open("http://www.google.com/","_blank",features);
    //Can only close windows opened by script.
    //window.close();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What combination of features listed here are you using?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do this was with IE (arg!).  This html/javascript works:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>showModalDialog</title>
</head>

<body onload="fnOpen()">

<script>


 function fnOpen() {
  var sFeatures = "dialogHeight: 500px;";
  window.showModalDialog("showModalDialog_target.htm", "", sFeatures)
 }
 </script>
 </body>
```